# AUAU BIOS keys not working and stuck in ASUS logo

Tags: windows-10, bios, asus-laptop

A few fay ago while watching a movie, my laptop freeze and my cpu fan start to spin quickly. I try to close the program but the laptop didn't respond to my command so I long press the power button to forcefully shutdown it. After that I press the power button to restart but it just stuck where it shows only a ASUS logo.
After that I can do only two things. Either I press the power button for shutdown or let it run (where it displays only a ASUS logo  ) and cpu gets hot.
I try to install Windows from bootable USB but I am not able to open the boot menu (boot menu keys ESC, F2, F8 not working). I researched and found that, boot menu keys don't work if the running program's files saved in the SSD(for fast boot up in next start up) like in a sleep mode.
Some articles also suggest that disassembling each part from laptop and assemble one by one would help to fix the problem but the seller put the seller put their warranty sticker on two screws so I cannot open it. And I cannot also bring it to them to fix it because of the lockdown.
If you have and suggestions, please share I will be very thankful.

Comment: Can you start with an ASUS hardware test USB and test the drive?

Comment: "ASUS hardware test usb" is that a software for laptop?

Comment: Yes. There should be an ASUS USB app for your machine or any ASUS machine.

Comment: I don't find the ASUS hardware test usb app

Comment: See whether this helps you :  https://asus-pc-diagnostics.en.lo4d.com/windows